# Summing in a subselect returning incorrect value

Tags: mysql, join, sum, subquery

I'm working on a query that counts the interactions that were done within a time period (clock out timestamp - clock in timestamp) for a specific shift type and I am summing the hours in a subselect as there isnt a way to join the tables. When  Ido this, it isnt counting the correct hours. It seems like it is counting all hours on that date without considering the shift type (in the query, the shift type is called 'Schedule'). Here is the query:

```
select a.sp_id, sum(s.ints_sent) as 'ints sent', 
(
select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.out_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (t.in_time))) 
from bi.support_sp_timeclocks t
join bi.support_agents_list sal
on t.agent_sp_id = sal.sp_id
where t.agent_sp_id = a.sp_id
) 
AS 'time clocked'
from bi.cc_agents_hourly_stats s
    join bi.support_agents_list a 
        on s.desk_id = a.desk_id
    where date_sent = '2014-01-04' 
and exists 
(
    select *
    from bi.support_sp_timeclocks t2
    join bi.support_sp_shifts_scheduled ss 
    on t2.shift_id = ss.pk_id
    join bi.support_agents_list sal 
    on sal.sp_id = ss.agent_sp_id
    where sal.desk_id = a.desk_id
    and timestamp(s.date_sent, maketime(s.hour_sent,00,00)) >= t2.in_time and    
    timestamp(s.date_sent, maketime(s.hour_sent,00,00)) < t2.out_time
    and  schedule = 'SMS'
)
group by date_sent, a.public_name
```

It returns this:

```
Agent ID  Interactions      time clocked
750705    16                420:47:21
418736    4             838:59:59
```

I know that for the first agent, the 'Time clocked' column should be .82 hours (The result will be in timestamp format) and the second agent, the result should be .32 hours.

Any thoughts on why this is occurring?

Comment: whwre have you valued bi ..its not in this code ?

Comment: is bi you involved in ur database ?

Comment: Bi is the database that the tables are in. It doesnt have to be added, but it I type in bi. first, it pops up a list of tables in that db so It just makes it faster when writing queries.

Answer (score 0):

The `838:59:59` is the telltale sign of overflow on the input to `SEC_TO_TIME()`.

Let's take a look at your subquery.  You have this aggregate query (it uses `SUM()`) but without any `GROUP BY`.

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.out_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (t.in_time))) 
  from bi.support_sp_timeclocks t
  join bi.support_agents_list sal on t.agent_sp_id = sal.sp_id
 where t.agent_sp_id = a.sp_id
```

It looks like you're computing the entire time logged by the agent since the beginning of time in your database.  If that's what you want, it's not clear why.

What do you get if you run this subquery on its own? (You don't need the `join` operation.)

```
select  t.agent_sp_id,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.out_time) 
                 - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (t.in_time)))   AS time_clocked
  from bi.support_sp_timeclocks t
 group by t.agent_sp_id
```

Does it give you something that makes more sense in your application? (I doubt it.)

Would it make more sense to try this?

```
select  t.agent_sp_id,
        DATE(t.out_time) AS day,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.out_time) 
                 - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (t.in_time)))   AS time_clocked
  from bi.support_sp_timeclocks t
 group by t.agent_sp_id, DATE(t.out_time)
```

This will give you day-by-day time spent by each agent.

If you want to restrict your query to a particular day, you might try this.

```
select  t.agent_sp_id,
        DATE(t.out_time) AS day,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.out_time) 
                 - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (t.in_time)))   AS time_clocked
  from bi.support_sp_timeclocks t
 where t.out_time >= '2014-01-04'
   and t.out_time <  '2014-01-04' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 group by t.agent_sp_id, DATE(t.out_time)
```

Once you have debugged the subquery that computes time spent, you can join it to your other tables to get your report resultset.

I hope this helps.